# Ubuntu Desktop system restore?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-restore

We are using all the desktop ubuntu 8.04 to 10.04, we are looking same thing like system resorting to back date like windows feature. Around 500 desktop and 79 server we want to setup. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main component of this feature is [VSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968832(VS.85).aspx).  This can by achieved by setting up all your systems on [LVM](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/index.html) and using [snapshots](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html).  Setup your system to periodically create and delete snapshots.  Make sure you leave sufficient free space in your volume groups to hold enough snapshots for you to fit your requirements.

OTOH it may be better to setup a central server with lots of storage and then using something like dirvish or some other rsync-based backup.  Then allow users to access their data off the backup server.  If you are able doing both would be even better.  Having both snapshots on the clients and backups to a server would give you two levels of protection.

Comment: thanks a ton for your quick reply on our issues but most of the server and desktop are running without LVM